# Como aceder ao valor do primeiro .map()?

Tags: angular

Estou a fazer uma introdução ao redux com angular 4, e quando estava a fazer um @Effect() deparei com a seguinte questão:

```
@Effect()
private newUser = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserActions.NEW_USER)
    .map((action: UserActions.NewUser) => action.payload)
    .switchMap((userData: UserCreation) => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post<User>(this.urlService.postNewUserUrl(), userData, { headers, observe: 'body' });
    })
    .map(user => {
        return {type: AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN, payload: -->{email: userData.email, userData.password}}<--
    });
```

Como posso aceder ao valor emitido do primeiro .map() para poder usar nos operadores seguintes? Neste caso quero usar o que foi retornado para o switchMap() através do primeiro map().

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
@Effect()
private newUser = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserActions.NEW_USER)
    .map((action: UserActions.NewUser) => action.payload)
    .switchMap((userData: UserCreation) => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post<User>(this.urlService.postNewUserUrl(), userData, { headers, observe: 'body' })
        .map(user => {
            return {type: AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN, payload: {email: userData.email, password: userData.password} };
        });
    });
```